# list usb smart card reader

Tags: centos, usb, smartcard

I have a Centos virtual-machine with a smart card reader connected, or which is supposed to be connected.

How can I list on which usb port is connected and if the OS recognize it correctly?

I've tried `lsusb` and `usb-devices` already but I only see [image: default hubs]

I don't know the smart reader brand, Thanks for the help.

#### EDIT

Here is the log of my Java application trying to use the device

```
16:33:45,394 DEBUG http-bio-9090-exec-9 DeviceSelector:readModule:162 - libbit4xpki.so: slots count = 0
Jul 02, 2019 4:33:45 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: Smartcard device not found
it.comped.jdigitalsign.utils.LocalizedException: Smartcard device not found
at it.comped.jdigitalsign.crypt2.signers.sunp11.DeviceSelector.selectModule(DeviceSelector.java:120)
```

### SOLUTION

The problem is resolved, they changed VM settings. By the way I can say now `lsusb` and `usb-devices` commands correctly list the devices properties so they are correct to show if the device is connected or not.

Comment: "VMware" suspiciously looks like you are on a virtual machine, and not the physical machine, where the reader is supposedly connected.

Comment: Yes, that is a virtual machine, can you explain me better "not the physical machine, where the reader is supposedly connected" ?? I don't own the machine, I can't manage the VM and normally I would not resolve this kind of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, partial answer:

A virtual machine only sees the hardware that is provided to it. This can be "real" hardware that is "stolen" from the physical machine the VM runs on, or it can be "simulated" hardware like the VMware USB hub and mouse.

Not knowing your situation, assuming that an USB smart card reader is connected to the physical machine, it won't show up on the virtual machine at all, unless it is assigned to this machine.

So you need to ask whoever manages the VM to assign it to your machine.

Comment: The problem is resolved, they changed VM settings. By the way now lsusb and usb-devices commands lists correctly the devices properties so they are correct to show if the device is connected or not.

Comment: Yes. that's a consequence of the device now being automatically assigned to your VM.